# QML Application Keyboard Behavior on Surface Pro Tablet

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am using Qt 5.8 (vs 2015 32 bit).  When running my QML application on a Surface Pro tablet without a physical keyboard/mouse connected, the keyboard pops up regardless of whether I am currently attempting to type in a text box or not.  Changing the visibility of the text's parent does not close the keyboard.  It will just pop up the next time the user touches the application.
If the application is in full screen mode the keyboard pops up behind the application but the keyboard is still clickable making it impossible to click the application itself.
Any suggestions how to show/hide keyboard programmatically on demand?

This sample code produces the keyboard popup for me.  I have tried changing the focus of the text field to false if the user clicks enter or when the parent window is no longer visible but this has no effect.  I also attempted to use Qt.inputMethod.hide() when the parent window is no longer visible, but this has no effect.

main.qml

```
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    property bool showPage1: false

    MyPage1 {
        id: page1
        visible: showPage1
        width: 1/2 * parent.width
        height: parent.height /3
        anchors.left: parent.left
        Rectangle {
            width: 50
            height: 50
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.margins: 10
            color: "yellow"
            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                onClicked: console.log("page 1 corner clicked")
            }
        }


    }

    Rectangle {
        width: 50
        height: 50
        color: "blue"
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        anchors.margins: 10
        MouseArea {
            anchors.fill: parent
            onClicked: {
                showPage1 = !showPage1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

MyPage1.qml

```
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1


Rectangle {
    id: page1Root
    color: "pink"
    border.color: "red"
    border.width: 4
    anchors.fill: parent

    Text {
        text: "Page 1!"
        anchors.fill: parent

        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.topMargin: 10
        width: parent.width * 3/4
        height: 30
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    }

    TextField {
        id: myTextField
        width: parent.width * 3/4
        height: 50
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        text: "type something here"
        onTextChanged: {
            console.log("text changed to: " + text)
        }
        horizontalAlignment: TextEdit.AlignLeft
        verticalAlignment: TextEdit.AlignVCenter
        font.pixelSize: 22
//        Keys.onReturnPressed: {
//            focus = false
////            Qt.inputMethod.hide()
//        }
        onFocusChanged: console.log("focus changed: " + focus)
//        MouseArea {
//            anchors.fill: parent
//            onClicked: {
//                console.log("text field clicked!")
//                focus = true
//            }
//        }
    }

    onVisibleChanged: {
        console.log("page 1 root visible: " + visible)
        if (visible)
        {
            myTextField.forceActiveFocus()
        }
        else
        {
            myTextField.focus = false
//            Qt.inputMethod.hide()
        }
    }
}
```

In MyPage1.qml, I am listening for text changed to see if when the page is NOT visible and the user types on the keyboard did the text change, but I did not see any text changing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that a TextInput does NOT bring up a keyboard, so I will use that instead.